# reshape 4D numpy Array of the image is changing the images figures

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, keras, reshape

I want to change the 4d array of images from (50, 100, 100, 128) to (50,128, 100, 100) but when I plot the image after reshaping it the image was changed.
All the images are CT Scan image from 50 patients and I want to use them for 3d Resnet Convolution Neural Network. in addition, each patient has 128 slices of 100*100 pixels image.

original shape:

```py
data.shape

(50, 100, 100, 128)
```

the image from data

```
imgplot = plt.imshow(data[0,:,:,1])
plt.show()
```

[image: orginal image]

after reshaping

```py
rd = data.reshape(-1,128,100,100)
rd.shape

(50, 128, 100, 100)
```

```
imgplot = plt.imshow(rd [0,1,:,:])
plt.show()
```

[image: reshapingimage]

Also, I tried the transpose but nothing changed

```py
r2data = np.transpose(data)
r2data.shape

(128, 100, 100, 50)
```

Comment: I think you're looking for https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html Reshaping changes the shape but not the order of elements. To swap axes, use transpose.

Comment: dear @tilman151 I tried transpose but nothing changed

Comment: How exactly did you use the command? I'd suggest data = np.transpose(data, (0, 2, 3, 1)). This should move your channel dimension to the back.

Comment: @tilman151 the result is (50, 100, 128, 100)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `array.transpose()` with the desired order of axes:

```
# original 4D array
In [98]: data = np.random.random_sample((50, 100, 100, 128))

# move last axis to second position; reshapes data but would still be a `view`
In [99]: reshaped_data = data.transpose((0, -1, 1, 2))

In [100]: reshaped_data.shape
Out[100]: (50, 128, 100, 100)
```

---

If you really want a copy of the data after transposing, then you can force it to do so:

```
In [106]: reshaped_data = data.transpose((0, -1, 1, 2)).copy()

In [107]: reshaped_data.flags
Out[107]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```